# New custom content element on typo3 with a select option

Tags: typo3

I want to create a content element where the editor can chose an icon to display on the frontend.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
   'tt_content',
   'CType',
    [
        'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/Tca.xlf:yourextensionkey_newcontentelement',
        'ServiceCE',
        'example-registration',
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['ServiceCE'] = [
   'showitem' => '
      --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
         --palette--;;general,
            header; Header,
            bodytext;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel,
   ',
];
```

Here I'm creating the layout on the back-end to insert the content, with just a header and a bodytext.

Comment: what special version of TYPO3? what kind of icon? first hand an icon is just an image, so you could use image/text with Image CE. Or do you want a fix set of icons the user can select from?then you can combine it with categories. should the icon be associated to the whole page or an individual CE (with the option of one icon for each CE)?

Comment: I was thinking in just a peace of html like <i class="fa icon"></i>, the select will call this different html with a different class, the simplest way possible, I don't know about the rest of your questions, I just want to do it for learning. I'm in typo3 10

Comment: is this all you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a lot of possible solutions:

dependent whether the icon should be assigned to pages or content elements work with the table `pages` or `tt_content`

1. your extension will provied the list of icons:
   add an additional field with a select list for the icons to the records. put it into TCA (`Configuration/TCA/Override/<table>.php`). Make sure the value is the icon-name,   so you do not need additional replacements in FLUID.
   Add the rendering to the FLUID template where it belongs. As it should be available everywhere the Layout-templates would be a good place.
2. use `sys_categories`:
   use the build in categories for providing icons to any record.
   create some categories with either the icon as category image or use another field as the icon name. (You even could add another field especially for the icon name.)
   For the rendering of `pages` or `tt_content` add a data processor to get the assigned `sys_category`-records of the data record and then render the first/all icon(s) of the record in the Layout-templates.